# Apache solr confusion with solr commit and indexing

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a doubt regarding Apache Solr

1. I create a core called "sampleCore" added xml data and indexed data using posts.jar
2. Added a new document using following url :-

curl http://localhost:8983/solr/sampleCore/update?commitWithin=1000 -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary 'testdoc5'

Still this newly added document is not showing up in solr.

When i reindex the data using posts.jar it shows up.

What is the use of commit then? Do i need to index the data every time i add/remove a document from solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are right, by default `update` is not committed for performance reason, thus you can't see it.

This link describes ways to commit document:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Near+Real+Time+Searching

There several ways to achieve NRT:

- add param `commit=true`, a hard commit, it's costly
- add param `optimize=true`, like hard commit, but even more costly, because it put all segments into a single segment.
- add param `commitWithin=<milliseconds>`, as used in your question, it's a soft commit, which is less costly, but won't sync to slave in cloud mode.

I tested `commitWithin=<milliseconds>` via:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/dummy/update?wt=json&indent=true&commitWithin=2000" -d '[
{"id":"4", "name":"Bob Smith", "create_date":"2016-02-16T14:36:12Z"}
]'
```

After 2 seconds, it's searchable. It should work.

In your case you need wait 1 second, and don't query the slave replication, query the master if you are using cloud mode.

I am also not quite familiar with solr, but hopes this could help.

---

### @Update:

Just tried it with xml data, it also works in my solr (*5.4.1, on linux*), it's searchable within 2 seconds.

refer: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers

e.g

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/dummy/update?wt=json&indent=true&commitWithin=2000" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">5</field>
    <field name="name">Jennifer Aniston</field>
    <field name="create_date">2016-02-16T23:10:21Z</field>
  </doc>
</add>'
```

I didn't do any additional config for xml, wondering did you change default config about NRT.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is not working for me :(. Here is what i tried :-

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:8983/solr/simplecore/update" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<add><doc><field name="id">testdoc7</field></doc></add>'

Comment: @ParitoshAhuja You r right, my fault, I updated the answer, hope it could help ...

Comment: Thanks mate there seem to be an issue with some configuration i guess, The doc is still not showing up. I am not using Solr Cloud.

Comment: It's working for json data, i think there is some problem with how xml data is indexed using this curl command

Comment: @ParitoshAhuja I tested with xml format, it also works, I updated the answer. In the url from above comment need change `update;` to `update?`, not sure did you write it correctly in your test url.

Comment: I guess that was it! ty :)